# python Constraints - constraining the amount

Tags: python, constraints, constraint-programming

I have a constraint problem that I'm trying to solve with [python-constraint](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-constraint)

So let's say I have 3 locations: `loc1,...loc3`

Also, I have 7 devices: `device1,...device7`

Max amount of devices in each location: `loc1:3, loc2:4, loc3:2`
(for example maximum of 3 devices in `loc1` and so on...)

And some constraints about the locations and the devices:

`loc1: device1, device3, device7`,

`loc2: device1, device3, device4, device5, device6, device7`

`loc3: device2, device4, device5, device6`

(meaning for example only `device1`, `device3` and `device7` can be in `loc1`.)

I'm trying to get a set of possible options for devices in locations.

```
    from constraint import *
    problem = Problem()
        for key in locations_devices_dict:
           problem.addVariable(key,locations_devices_dict[key])
           # problem.addVariable("loc1", ['device1', 'device3', 'device7'])
   problem.addConstraint(AllDifferentConstraint())
```

and I'm stuck on how to do the constrains. I've tried:

```
problem.addConstraint(MaxSumConstraint(3), 'loc1')
```

but it doesn't work, MaxSumConstraint does not sum what I need.

**All devices must be placed somewhere**

possible solution:

```
loc1: device1, device3
loc2: device4, device6, device7
loc3: device2, device5
```

Anyone has an idea?

(another python package/not to use any package, is also good idea if someone has any suggestions...)

Comment: This is a little bit like an assignment problem. So have a boolean variables x[i,j] that indicate if device i does to location j. Then we have sum(j,x[i,j])=1 and sum(i,x[i,j])<=maxloc[j]. Finally allow only x[i,j]=1 where appropriate. This is easily coded.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen sorry, I don't see how it is easily coded. I want all the possible solutions, how do I do it efficient? this is only an example, the real problem I have is larger...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simple assignment-like model:

[image]

So we have a binary variable indicating if device *d* is assigned to location *L*. The linear constraints are just:

- assign each device to one location
- each location has a maximum number of devices
- make sure to use only allowed assignments (modeled above by `allowed(L,d)`)

This problem can be handled by any constraint solver.

Enumerating all possible solutions is a bit dangerous. For large instances there are just way too many. Even for this small problem we already have 25 solutions:

[image]

For large problems this number will be astronomically large.

Using the Python constraint package this can look like:

```
from constraint import *

D = 7 # number of devices
L = 3 # number of locations

maxdev = [3,4,2]
allowed = [[1,3,7],[1,3,4,5,6,7],[2,4,5,6]]

problem = Problem()
problem.addVariables(["x_L%d_d%d" %(loc+1,d+1) for loc in range(L) for d in range(D) if d+1 in allowed[loc]],[0,1])
for loc in range(L):
    problem.addConstraint(MaxSumConstraint(maxdev[loc]),["x_L%d_d%d" %(loc+1,d+1) for d in range(D) if d+1 in allowed[loc]])
for d in range(D):
    problem.addConstraint(ExactSumConstraint(1),["x_L%d_d%d" %(loc+1,d+1) for loc in range(L) if d+1 in allowed[loc]])

S = problem.getSolutions()
n = len(S)
n
```

For large problems you may want to use dicts to speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

**edit:** I wrote this answer  before I saw @ErwinKalvelagen's code. So I did not check his solution...

So I used @ErwinKalvelagen approach and created a matrix that represented the probelm.
for each (i,j), x[i,j]=1 if device i can go to location j, 0 otherwise.

Then, I used `addConstraint(MaxSumConstraint(maxAmount[i]), row)` for each row - this is the constraint that represent the maximum devices in each location.

and `addConstraint(ExactSumConstraint(1), col)` for each column - this is the constraint that each device can be placed only in one location.

next, I took all x[i,j]=0 (device i can not be in location j) and for each t(i,j) `addConstraint(lambda var, val=0: var == val, (t,))`

This problem is similar to the sudoku problem, and I used [this](https://simplapi.wordpress.com/2012/11/02/python-constraint-and-sudoku/) example for help

The matrix for my example above is:

```
(devices:) 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
     loc1: 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
     loc2: 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
     loc3: 0 1 0 1 1 1 0
```

My code:

```
        problem = Problem()
        rows = range(locations_amount)
        cols = range(devices_amount)
        matrix = [(row, col) for row in rows for col in cols]
        problem.addVariables(matrix, range(0, 2)) #each cell can get 0 or 1
        rowSet = [zip([el] * len(cols), cols) for el in rows]
        colSet = [zip(rows, [el] * len(rows)) for el in cols]

        rowsConstrains = getRowConstrains() # list that has the maximum amount in each location(3,4,2) 
                                            #from my example: loc1:3, loc2:4, loc3:2 

        for i,row in enumerate(rowSet):
            problem.addConstraint(MaxSumConstraint(rowsConstrains[i]), row)
        for col in colSet:
            problem.addConstraint(ExactSumConstraint(1), col)

        s = getLocationsSet() # set that has all the tuples that x[i,j] = 1

        for i, loc in enumerate(locations_list):
            for j, iot in enumerate(devices_list):
                t=(i,j)
                if t in s:
                    continue
                problem.addConstraint(lambda var, val=0: var == val, (t,)) # the value in these cells must be 0

        solver = problem.getSolution()
```

example for a solution:

```
(devices:) 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
     loc1: 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
     loc2: 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
     loc3: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```